# MVC3 Jquery viewdata disable button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The following piece of code is not disabling the html button. I am using MVC3 razor . Can anyone point out where I am going wrong

```
@{
   bool disablebutton = bool.Parse(ViewData["Disablebutton"].ToString());        
 }    

 $(document).ready(function () {  
   if (@disablebutton) {
     $('#abc').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }       
 });
```

Comment: Need more context. button with id abc is in the document?  What's the resulting HTML look like (i.e. view source in browser and paste that, not just your razor code)?

Comment: The below code is from view source                            <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {  
   if (True) {
     $('#abc').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }       
 });

 </script>
 <input type="button" value="abc" id="abc"  />

Comment: Added an answer with my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in your question, there's your problem: "True" is not valid Javascript.  It has to be `true` all lowercase.  Look at your JS error console and I'm sure you'll have an error.

You can do `if (@disablebutton.ToLower())`

The above is just one way of resolving your issue.  You need to be careful when mixing server-side with client-side.